# Как правильно искать нужные библиотеки в Java API

Tags: java, api

Хотел поинтересоваться, как лучше или правильно искать нужные библиотеки в Java, а также как ими пользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вопрос довольно абстрактный. На мой взгляд, к этому вопросу следует подходить с другой стороны. У вас есть задача - вы думаете над ее реализацией.
 К примеру, ваша задача - получить информацию с сайта. Вы моделируете, бла-бла-бла, и приходить у тому, как же получить именно получать информацию с сайта. Затем, ищете примеры, которые схожи с Вашей задачей. Узнаете, что не все следует писать руками, можно и библиотеку готовую подключить. Узнаете, что есть `jsoup`.
Следующий шаг - это чтение документации - обычно это самый простой и верный способ. Затем подключаете библиотеку, `maven`, `Ant`, `Gradle`...
И живете дальше!

Comment: А вообще как я понял, основная суть написания программы, это правильно подобрать нужные библиотеки и реализовать и у себя в коде?

Comment: @WolFRam это как посмотреть и куда). Если программа простая и учебная, то лучше писать все руками. Если же вы  проекте, то явно лучше взять что-то готовое, проверенное, и обработать под себя

Comment: А вообще практически на все возникающие проблемы, есть библиотеки которые могут их решить?

Comment: @WolFRam конечно, нет. Для больших проектов, команды пишут сами себе библиотеки, которые остаются в фирме. Ведь о факту, библиотека - это набор класса, имеющих что-то общее.

Comment: @WolFRam представьте себе, что вам дали стартап, занимающийся собачьими ошейниками, которые ловят импульсы пробегающих рядом собак... или любой другой бред, который явно никто до вас не делал. Во именно тут и проявляются все качества программиста

Comment: Спасибо вроде понял, крч для банальных, часто встречающихся проблем есть уже готовые библиотеки, а если нужно сделать что-то совершенно новое, то уже в силу идут личные знания.